# HTML, CSS - Aligning Buttons To The Center Of Page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I want to align some buttons to the center of the page. May I please know how can I do it here in my CSS.

```css
button {
  background-color: #6495ED;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  position: middle;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width: auto;">User Login</button>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto; ">Admin Login</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can add this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh; // stretch body to the whole page
  display: flex; // define a flex container
  flex-direction: column; // arrange items in column
  justify-content: center; // align vertically center
}
```

(Note that `position: middle` is *invalid*)

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #6495ED;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width: auto;">User Login</button>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto; ">Admin Login</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, sir. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: ok, so I guess I need to be more responsible with my answers... I answered a common duplicate... you have your answer in the duplicate that I've tagged except that you need to specify the `flex-direction` as `column`... :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Flexbox just wrap your `button`s in a `div` and set it's `position` to `absolute`, `top` to `50%`, `left` to `50%` and `transform` to `translate(-50%, -50%)`, also give the parent or the `body` element `position` `relative`.

Note that the `body` or parent that contains the `.buttons-holder` has to be of defined `height`.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

.buttons-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  background: #6495ED;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-holder">
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto">User Login</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto">Admin Login</button>
</div>
```